# How to choose embedding size for tensorflow recommender system

Tags: tensorflow, recommender-system, embeddings

I am going to build a recommender system using TensorFlow recommender and the two-tower-model. I have wondered, how to choose the size of the embedding dimension. Are there any papers on this for large scale recommender systems? For the example, Google chose a size of 32 dimensions for the movie recommender. My vocabulary contains around 30,000 different items.

Help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, the size of the embedding layer is not an important hyperparameter.

Research has found embeddings dimension [lower than ~19 are not performant](https://aclanthology.org/I17-2006/) and there is [asymptotic improvement after ~200 dimensions](https://nlp.stanford.edu/pubs/glove.pdf).

Multiples of 32 are chosen for hardware efficiency.